# mac: change icon of app launched with arguments?

Tags: macos, mac, icons, dock

I launched firefox from the Terminal with some command line arguments. It appears in the doc and now I want to change the icon from the firefox icon to something else and keep it in the dock. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a simple application that calls Firefox with the desired arguments.
The simplest way to do this is to create an application running a shell script in Automator. The shell script should call your program with arguments, like this:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -ProfileManager &
```

[image]

Save it as an **application** (not workflow) where you like. You can then [change the application icon](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2493) using Finder. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on the application, click on the thumbnail, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste your custom icon.

Then drag the newly created executable to the Dock.

Comment: Wouldn't this "launcher" quit immediately? Also, application icons work differently from document icons, I don't think the copy/paste in *Get Info* works.

Comment: Copy/paste works for sure, I've tried it. The launcher quits immediately, but it's still a nice solution for launching applications from the Dock.